# Empty tag reading out CSV to array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm converting a csv file to an array.
Then I'm reading out the array with php and do a foreach.

The strange thing I have know is that for a certain product an item in the array does not get a value.

To be more clear. When I do a print_r of they array I get following output:

```
[2494] => Array
    (
        [0] => 874082
        [1] => DVR DL 8X,USB2.0
        [2] => Samsung
        [3] => SE-208GB/RSBD
        [4] => Black,Ultra Slim,Retail
        [5] => PARENT PRODUCT GROUP
        [6] => External DVD burner
        [7] => S
        [8] => 8806086112031
        [9] => 45
        [10] => 
        [11] => 17,97
        [12] => 0,04
        [13] => 0,00
        [14] => 0,00
        [15] => 0,00
        [16] => 0
        [17] => SE-208GB/R
```

So on [11] you can see the price.
But when I echo this field it is empty. While for all other products I can echo the price.

I can not find an answer for this problem. Can anybody help me troubleshooting this?

Kr,

Comment: `echo $myArray[2494][11];` and what do you see?

Comment: nothing, that is the problem and only for a certain row